# How to type a component which has flatlist with forwadRef in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

So I have a flatlist as a custom component and I use it in `App` component. However in `App`, `item` parameter of `renderItem` has `unknown` type. I know this is an expected behavior but I am not sure how to use generics in `CustomFlatList`.

```
import React, { forwardRef } from "react"
import { FlatList, FlatListProps, Text, View } from "react-native"

interface Props<T> {
    flatListProps: FlatListProps<T>
}

const CustomFlatList = forwardRef<any, Props<unknown>>((props, ref) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <FlatList {...props.flatListProps} />
        </View>
    )
})

const App: React.FC = () => {
    return <View>
        <CustomFlatList flatListProps={{
            data: [1, 2, 3],
            renderItem: ({ item }) => <Text>{item}</Text> // item type is unknown here
        }} />
    </View>
}

export default App
```

Comment: there is a good article about it.
https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react-generic-forward-refs/